# have a column in c# listview truncated at the beginning instead of the end

Tags: c#, listview

in c#, i have a listview control. i want the text fields in ONE of the columns to get truncated at the beginning instead of the end.

i.e. i want the text fields in column 2 to read:

...name1

...name2

...name3

instead of

filena...

filena...

filena...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
        listView1.DrawColumnHeader +=listView1_DrawColumnHeader;
        listView1.DrawSubItem+=listView1_DrawSubItem;
    }


    private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawText();
    }

    private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.Right);
    }
```

if it's just one specific column that you would like to see this behavior say col index = 5 then try

```
    private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
        {
            e.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.Right);
        }
        else
        {
            e.DrawText();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, however i do not get the same table layout as defined before using ownerdraw=true (e.g. different column widths)